# PHP pass array by reference

Tags: php, arrays, reference

1. What is a correct way to use `array_splice` in PHP? The function header clearly says:

   `array_splice ( array &$input , int $offset...` so it should accept reference as a first argument.

   However, a line

   `array_push(&$this->contextsIds, $contextId);`

   Triggers an error **Deprecated: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated in ... line 132**
2. How do I return a reference to an array? I have:

   ```
   public function &getContextsIds() {
       return is_array($this->contextsIds) ? $this->contextsIds : array();    
   }
   ```

   but it says **Notice: Only variable references should be returned by reference**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The function is already declared to take a reference (`array &$input`); you don't need the `&` again when calling the function. Just call it like this:

   ```
   array_push($this->contextsIds, $contextId);
   ```
2. As the message says, you should only return actual variables by reference, not mere values. In your example, there are two such instances: the `? :` operator evaluates to a value, and also `array()` by itself is just a value not bound to any variable. You should probably just return your class member regardless of whether it is empty or not:

   ```
   return $this->contextIds;
   ```

Comment: Thanks! Would you please help me on the second one that I've added?

Comment: "regardless of whether it is empty or not" He's testing `is_array()`

Comment: @BoltClock: I noticed that, but I'm guessing that he is likely testing if it's empty. I'll wait for the OP's response.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you return a reference to an array, especially in the code you provided:

```
public function &getContextsIds() {
    return is_array($this->contextsIds) ? $this->contextsIds : array();    
}
```

When that function is would work, it could return a reference to an empty array, I could do with it what I want and change it as much as I'd like, but it wouldn't have any effect, because it was just an empty array without any further reference at all..